# If Erdős Conjecture on arithmetic progressions is true, and $A$ is large, then does there exist a consecutive A.P. of $A$ of length $k$ for every $k?$

Tags: integers, arithmetic-progressions, erdos-conjecture

Question 1: If [Erdős Conjecture on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions) is true, and $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ is large, then does $A$ contain a *consecutive* A.P. of $A$ of length $k;\ \lbrace{a_{m+1}, a_{m+2},\ldots, a_{m+k}\rbrace},\ $ for every $k\in\mathbb{N}?$

Maybe this is true by [Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)?